# Apache Solr own grouping in autocomplete

Tags: 7, ajax, search

The [apache solr autocomplete](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr_autocomplete) module don't work for me.
I try to achive a relative complex autocomplete,
my target is to achive this on the autocomplete:

**Search for "searchword":**
-Facet for type/bundle
-Facets based on the results
Show all results for "searchword"

As example:
**Search for "test":**
Download (176)
Systems (100)
News (20)
Services (5)
**Systems**
System 1
System n
**Services**
Service 1
Service n
**Show all results for "test"**

Any suggestions how I could get this?

Edit: I use [apache solr search](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr) for this so no [search api](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) hook here
(miss some functions in the [search api](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) based)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Module [Search Autocomplete](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_autocomplete) will work on this base.
So I just need to add a top Layer for the facet and group the results.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to write your own query according to results you want to get.
below link may help you in this.

https://www.drupal.org/node/2203775

Comment: already thought about a own module, but no search api in this system (see edit).

Comment: well, you can write your own custom module. That module will alter the query which is working for default autocomplete feature. To add more filter you can use the below code:try {
        $solr = apachesolr_get_solr();
        $params = array(
      'rows' => $count_limit,
      'sort' => 'created desc',
      'qt' => 'standard',
   'wt' => 'standard',
        );                                                                        } catch (Exception $e) {
        watchdog('module name', 'apachesolr: ' . nl2br(check_plain($e->getMessage())), NULL, WATCHDOG_ERROR);
        return NULL;
    }

Comment: Also you can use:$response = $solr->search($query, $params);  //dpm($response); to perform the search.Also there is a function that can be used is :$query->add_filter();